# Modifying struct instance using call to name in function parameter

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am attempting to use Parse to call up some variables and put them into a struct that is already initialized. The calling of the variables is happening smoothly and the data is available, but the inputing of the class into the function is not happening.

'unit' is a struct that has the name, hp, attack, etc. variables contained within it.

Is it not possible to pass along an instance of a struct and modify it's values like this? It would save me a lot of copy-pasting code to do it this way.

Thanks for your help!

```
func fetchStats(name: String, inout nameOfClass: unit) {
var unitStatArray = []
let query = PFQuery(className: "UnitStats")
query.whereKey("name", equalTo: name)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?)->Void in

  if (error == nil && objects != nil){ unitStatArray = objects! }
  nameOfClass.name = "\(unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("name")!)"
  print("class name is \(nameOfClass.name)")
  print("cannon name is \(cannon.name)")
  nameOfClass.hitPoints =      unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("hitPoints") as! Double
  nameOfClass.hitPointsMax =   unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("hitPointsMax") as! Double
  nameOfClass.attack =         unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("attack") as! Double
  nameOfClass.defense =        unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("defense") as! Double
  nameOfClass.rangedAttack =   unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("rangedAttack") as! Double
  nameOfClass.rangedDefense =  unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("rangedDefense") as! Double
  nameOfClass.cost =           unitStatArray[0].objectForKey("cost") as! Int


}

}


fetchStats("3-inch Ordnance Rifle", nameOfClass: &cannon)
```

Comment: That's a concurrency issue. ``fetchStats`` has finished before the passed block given to ``findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock``is executed. The block is executed asynchronuous - you possibly need to add a callback or block to ``fetchStats`` that takes and processes the modified ``nameOfClass``

Comment: Could you clarify with a bit of code? I am not quite sure what you mean. Thanks again for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt to explain what I had in mind when writing my comment above.
Because there's an asynchronous call to `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, the `inout` won't help you here. The idea is to add a callback `fetched` like this:

```
func fetchStats(name: String, var nameOfClass: unit, fetched: unit -> ()) {
  // your code as above
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    // your code as above plus the following statement:
    fetched(nameOfClass)
  }
}
```

This can be called with

```
fetchStats("3-inch Ordnance Rifle", nameOfClass: cannon) { newNameOfClass in
  nameOfClass = newNameOfClass
}
```

(all of this code has not been tested)

The point is that you understand that your code is asynchronous (I know, I'm repeating myself). After you have called `fetchStats` you don't know when the callback (here: the assignment `nameOfClass = newNameOfClass`) will be executed. You cannot assume the assignment has been done after `fetchStats` has returned.

So whatever you need to do with the changed `nameOfClass`: the corresponding statements must go into the callback:

```
fetchStats("3-inch Ordnance Rifle", nameOfClass: cannon) { newNameOfClass in
  // do whatever you want with the received newNameOfClass
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am still struggling. Thanks for trying.

What I don't understand is when I print the variables to test them, they print properly. The struct instance parameters cannot be overridden though. Is there a better way to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: I don't know if I correctly understand your problem, but instead of modifying the input (the ``nameOfClass`` variable) you probably should return a new instance.

Comment: My issue is that I want the new instance to have the same name as the declared instance. I am basically pulling unit stats from the server, then setting all units of that type to have the same basic unit stats when they're initialized.